# Javascript Event Handlers supported on SVG by Firefox 3.5

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I have been wracking my brains for the whole day on this one. It appears that the SVG DOM manipulations supported by Firefox 3.5 are very limited. A few properties like this.style.cursor can be successfully manipulated with an onmouseover handler but interesting properties like this.style.fill or this.style.stroke cannot be!

Does anybody know of a better way to achieve a simple change in border / outline color on mouse over?

Or is the whole idea of SVG allowing DOM manipulations merely an ugly infant?

Comment: Oh, well. SVG + JavaScript is IMHO one part of the sparkling future of the next-generation open web. No sarcasm intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SVG/Scripting). The problem is, that the `style` property implementation in FF is indeed quite incomplete. You can circumvent this, however, using the also-standardized `setProperty()` method:

```
svgElement.style.setProperty("fill-opacity", "0.0", "")
```

(the third parameter allows for adding pseudo-classes).

For a simple mouse-over effect use an embedded (or external) stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
rect { fill: green; }
rect:hover { fill: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: +1: worked for me on the `stroke` property in a quick test in Firebug.

Comment: @NickFitz: I now have several dozen grey hairs more. I got one for every hour I spent to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS for this.

```
#myrec:hover {
  /* set styles in here /*
}
```

Also check these libraries out.

http://raphaeljs.com/
http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/

Answer (score 0):

To be fair the manipulations you seem to want only involve DOM 2 Style, not SVG DOM in particular.